# Android RTL support for shapes corners radius

Tags: android, right-to-left, shapes

I notice that there is no `bottomEndRadius` in shapes but instead just `bottomRightRadius`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Is there any work around this to support right-to-left layouts?

Comment: A [ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#shape-drawable) object can be a good option when you want to _dynamically_ draw a two-dimensional graphic.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've found is to use a separate dir for RTL resources. For instance, drawable-ldrtl/ for graphics or layout-ldrtl/ for layouts.

Look at this doc for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#MirroringAddResources